# How to launch a third party plugin and use methods with it in eclipse in my own code?

Tags: eclipse, testing, eclipse-plugin, mutation-testing, pitest

I'm doing a project to get the mutation score of each test I wrote, every time I change the input, I want to call the eclipse plugin called Pitclipse and return the mutation score corresponding to the input.

In fact this is an optimization problem where mutation score is the object function to be maximized, I want to find test cases with high mutation score.

Do you have any idea how to launch this third party plugin everytime I call it on my own code?

Comment: Eclipse plugins can only be used by other Eclipse plugins - so are you writing a plugin?

Comment: The fact is I'm doing a project that I have to call the plugin repeatly and return a return value of one method in the plugin.

Comment: If I must call another plugin in plugin, does it mean that I have to convert my current project into a plugin?

Comment: As I said an Eclipse plugin can only be used by another Eclipse plugin, so, yes, you have to write a plugin.

Comment: I suggest that instead of trying to call the eclipse plugin you use http://pitest.org - the tool that Pitclipse wraps. This will be much easier to call programatically.